# Reducing map look-up times

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables

Is there a significant difference in speed when scaling the following two program structures:

```
map<string, std::function<string()>> myMap = {
    {"hello", [](){ return " world"; }}
};

int main()
{
    cout << "hello" << myMap["hello"]();
    return 0;
}
```

vs.

```
int main()
{
    map<string, std::function<string()>> myMap;
    myMap["hello"] = [](){ return " world"; };

    cout << "hello" << myMap["hello"]();

    return 0;
}
```

One part of me wants to think that the globally initialized `myMap` will be faster, but since map is part of `stl`, that makes me think it's impossible for the actual map to be populated until runtime, since it uses dynamic memory allocation internally (unlike a globally initialized int array, which is baked into the executable, for example). Am I correct in thinking these two methods are virtually identical as far as reducing the amount of time to look-up something in a map?

Comment: Measure it! That's the best way to know. Wrap a class around a LOT of `std::map`s, and use your constructor to time! see what you find! I would expect no difference at all since both are runtime but hey, nothing wrong in verifying.

Comment: An acceptable performance question requires: (1) you profile your code, and run into something unexpected/sub optimal (fail) (2) your code is complete (pass) (3) you tell us your compiler flags (fail) and they include optimization (fail) (4) the things being tested are treated symmetrically (no one-after-another) (pass).  Your question scores a 2/5.  Fix those issues and I'll revert the -1.  (search SO for C++ performance questions: they almost all contain comments asking for pretty much this list.  The -1 is for not being useful, and for failing to do basic research first.) @Yakk me when done

Comment: @Yakk I'm not interested in profiling code over something as simple as this because I don't really consider it a "performance question." My question at its core is whether or not globally initialized stl containers have any speed benefit/overhead reduction in C++11 vs. locally-initialized stl containers that I'm not aware of. It would be like if I asked if there were any overhead difference between a large globally initialized array of strings in C vs. a locally initialized array of strings in C. Clearly there is, since the former will actually have its own section in the executable (text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the global map can't be initialized until the program starts running. There is no performance difference between the two forms of initialization, only a difference of whether it happens before or after `main` starts. Thee is no difference in lookup time when accessing the map either.

Unlike C programs, a C++ program has a *dynamic initialization* phase when globals that require construction at runtime are initialized. That is distinct from *static initialization*, which is how simple types (such as an array of ints with constant initializers) get their values, which is typically done at compile-time and baked into the executable.